# Push SVector into vector of SVector in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to push a SVector (provided by [JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl)) into a vector of SVector. The following code is my trial:

```
using StaticArrays
lst = Vector{SVector{2, Float64}}[]
a = SVector(1, 2)
push!(lst, a)
```

But it causes the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type SArray{Tuple{2},Float64,1,2}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are making is that you create an `Array` of `Array` of an `SVector`. `T[]` creates an empty array of type `T`.

```
# This creates an empty array of type Float64
julia> lst = Float64[]
0-element Array{Float64,1}

# This creates an empty array of a Float64 array
julia> lst = Vector{Float64}[]
0-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}
```

So you need to redefine your array as an array of `SVector`.

```
julia> lst = SVector{2, Float64}[] # an empty 1D array(i.e. Vector) of `SVector`
0-element Array{SArray{Tuple{2},Float64,1,2},1}

julia> a = SVector(1, 2)
2-element SArray{Tuple{2},Int64,1,2}:
 1
 2

julia> push!(lst, a)
1-element Array{SArray{Tuple{2},Float64,1,2},1}:
 [1.0, 2.0]
```

You can also use this instead of your way of empty array definition:

```
lst = Vector{SVector{2, Float64}}(undef, 0) # this creates a `Vector` of `SVector` of size 0 (empty)
```